# Azure Data Factory Not Accepting Parameter: ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,The value of the property 'tableName' is invalid: '

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to parameterize the sending of Data to our AzureSQLDB. I have done this many times, but for someone reason keep on getting the error:
[image]

My Copy Data Source is as follows:
[image]

[image]

And my Connection is as follows:
[image]

I can't see any thing wrong with this setup. However, I keep on getting the error that the Value cannot be NULL.
However, if I were hardcode the connection as follows, it would be successful

[image]

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What parameter value did you give while running the pipeline?

Comment: value called propertyoutlet

Comment: The error indicates a reference to "tableName", but the screenshots reference "TableName". The cases are not the same.

Comment: @JoelCochran, once a changed from TableName to "tableName" it worked. Good catch. Thank you

Comment: did the error get resolved?

Comment: Yes thank you. Thanks for reaching out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error code
> InvalidParameter
> Failure type User configuration issue
> Details
> ErrorCode=InvalidParameter, Type=Microsoft.Data Transfer.Common.Shared.Hybrid DeliveryException, Message=The value of the property 'tableName' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: tableName'.,Source=,"Type=System.ArgumentNullException, Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: tableName,Source=Microsoft.Data Transfer.DataContracts,'

- As Joel Cochron suggested in comment section, the error message is because of the parameter created and parameter used in datasets are having different cases.
- Keep the parameter name in both places same, so that this error will not occur while debugging the pipeline.
- In this case, Change the parameter name from `TableName` to `tableName` in source settings.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for reaching out. Going to try your suggestion now. I will let you know how I get on